# Produce jar file from maven plugin source code

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Well my project get all maven plugins from an internal server. in this server all the plugins are in a jar format but the new plugins that I am getting from Apache site is in src format.

So, the question is how to produce a jar from this src code?

I tried to get the plugin by adding it to the pom as normally do, but it turns out that we 'must' get it from the local server instead. Let's say that this is a requirment. So I should add it there. And to do so, I need a jar file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have the source code of a Maven plugin and you need to build a JAR from it, you can follow these steps:

**Set Up a Maven Project:**
Create a new Maven project or use an existing one to build the JAR. Make sure that you have the necessary directory structure (src/main/java) and a valid pom.xml in place.

**Add the Source Code:**
Copy the source code of the Maven plugin into the appropriate package directory under src/main/java. Ensure that the directory structure matches the package structure in the source code.

**Configure the pom.xml:**
In the pom.xml, define the plugin's coordinates and packaging as "maven-plugin". Also, make sure to specify the correct version of the Maven Plugin API. Here's an example:

```
<project>
    ...
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>your.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    ...
</project>
```

then simply generate jar by maven commands and use it

```
mvn clean package
```

Install the JAR to Your Local Repository:

```
mvn install
```

Comment: By running the mvn install in the plugin or at project that it is using the plugin the jar is created at your repository. Alternatively at the maven site you have two options, you may download the source or the bin of a maven version. the bin one has alla the jars.